# PHP Find specific links and add to variable

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a messaging system and when a user posts a link to a profile that exists on my website within the message, I would like to "attach" the user's information to the message.

The profile's link are formatted as follows: `http://www.mydomain.com/profile/{id}`

So using PHP I would like to extract the `ID` from the URL and add some more information to a variable.

If there are multiple profile URLs within the message I would like to have to multiple profile attachments.

All of the attachments will be placed into a variable. so for every URL found I would like to add some information into a variable e.g. `$attachments`

Could anyone point me into the correct direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all ID from profile URLs in messages you can use [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with something similar to

`#http://www.mydomain.com/profile/(\d+)#`

I assumed that `id` is number.

Comment: Actually, you assumed `id` is a nonnegative integer.  This may be ambiguous to someone new to RegEx.  `\d` denotes any digit from 0 to 9.  `+` denotes there are 1 or more of these digits from 0 to 9.  Also, I would personally use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), not `preg_match_all()` for this.  There will only be one match in this string, so there is no need for the additional overhead or complexity.

Comment: `If there are multiple profile URLs within the message` - I think more then one match. And you are right about digits. SO ask only for `correct direction` so link to `preg_match_all()` was most important part of answer (as for me).